# Whats the expiry time for access token in Azure Managed Identity?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am using the below piece of code to generate access token to connect my application code to Azure SQL using AAD auth. I needed to find out the expiry time of this token

To find the expiry, I tried two ways:

1) Create one console app that connects to Azure SQL and perform some data operations using AAD auth. Run this app continuously in a loop for more than a hour. Here the token was found to expire after 1 hr

2) Create a Web App and host in iisexpress. In the web app, write the same data access code as in Console app. Invoke the Web App url in a loop multiple times for more than a hour. Here also the token was expiring in about an hr

3) Same as point 2 except for the fact that the Web App is hosted in Azure with Managed Identities enabled. Here the token wasn't expiring after 1 hr.

So the token expiry is linked to the environment from which the call is made. I need to find out the exact expiry time for token for different scenarios. I couldn't find any documentation. All that I find is that the token will be cached in memory and will be renewed when expired.

```
var provider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
string token = provider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connstring");
con.AccessToken = token;
```

Comment: Are you getting the token from the provider every time before the call? It automatically refreshes the token when necessary.

Comment: Yes, the token is obtained every time. First time the call will take 3-4 seconds..Next time onwards it will happen in milliseconds until it expires. Since there's a delay in getting in new token I want to know how often we can expect this delay.

Answer (score 6):

Managed Identity access tokens expire in 24 hours.

Tokens acquired via the App Authentication library currently are refreshed when less than 5 minutes remains until they expire.
So it caches the token for 23 hours 55 minutes in the default case.

You can see where the library defines the expiry time here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/e3bc748ea19040f9f18375aa907246f5b8b882a7/src/SdkCommon/AppAuthentication/Azure.Services.AppAuthentication/AppAuthenticationResult.cs#L40-L44

You should always cache the tokens until less than 5 minutes remains as the Managed Identity endpoint itself caches the tokens until that time.
If you try to get a new token when more than 5 minutes remains, you will just get the same token.

Comment: +1 You can actually use the GetAuthenticationResultAsync method that returns the AccessToken and the ExpiresOn property

Answer (score 2):

That hasn't been my experience.  In a similar scenario you provided, I was able to use a token for 24hrs, and even in the generation process I could see where the token lifetime was set (86400 sec).  But, that was using a VM system-assigned managed ID. This was tested within the last week.

We have seen differences in token lifetimes depending which service class/category is requesting the token (eg. Compute(VM), Management and Governance(AA), etc)